# List values found in string (function or VBA)

Tags: arrays, vba, string, find

I have an issue with Excel.
I have a list of emails. In these messages I want to find particular data (account numbers) and list them in next columns (if found) by just writing their names down.
List of accounts I want to find is in another spreadsheet ('account list').

Can I do it via some simple function (array formulas run very slow on my PC and can make my excel 'not responding') or VBA code?

Please find below a link to an excel file with some sample data.

I would be very grateful for help and advice! Unfortunately I cannot find solution to this issue...
https://uploadfiles.io/pfizs
[Link to excel file](https://ufile.io/pfizs)

Kind regards,
Mike

Dear All, 
I received a solution, which I want to share with you:

```
Sub FindAccount()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Set rngList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set ws1 = Sheets("sample messages")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("account list")
    Dim i&, v1 As Range, v2 As Range, fn
    Set v1 = ws1.Range("F2", ws1.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set v2 = ws2.Range("A1", ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    For Each rng2 In v2
        For Each rng1 In v1
            If InStr(1, rng1, rng2) > 0 Then
                ws1.Cells(rng1.Row, 7) = Trim(Mid(ws1.Cells(rng1.Row, 7) & ", " & rng2, 2, 9999))
            End If
        Next rng1
    Next rng2
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We'll need more information to properly help you: what have you tried so far, what specifically is going wrong, and do you have a minimal working example of the issue? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's also very unlikely that anyone will download a file of unknown origin :)

Comment: Enter sampe data there as text

Comment: Dear Roman, Please find below a link to the file: https://uploadfiles.io/pfizs

Comment: solutions should be posted as answers not within question.